RC522 ESP32C3 Xiao with Micropython Connection Issues
I have:
RC522 RFID Module
ESP32C3 with Micropython
I am trying to get the RC522 module connected over SPI (either hardware or SoftSPI). I haven't had any success connecting to it after trying a sketch (below) and a few variants of micropython RC522 libraries (one example below). I am seeing a lot of conflicting advice on what pins to use for SPI on the ESP32C3. Seeed studio claims SCK D8, MISO D9, and MOSI D10, while the following code would imply otherwise:
>>> spi = SPI(1)
>>> spi
SPI(id=1, baudrate=500000, polarity=0, phase=0, bits=8, firstbit=0, sck=6, mosi=7, miso=2)

Here is one variant of a sketch I have tried:
from mfrc522 import MFRC522
from machine import Pin, SoftSPI
from machine import SPI

spi = SPI(1, baudrate=500000, polarity=0, phase=0, sck=Pin(6), mosi=Pin(7), miso=Pin(2))
# To use SoftSPI,
# from machine import SOftSPI
# spi = SoftSPI(baudrate=100000, polarity=0, phase=0, sck=sck, mosi=mosi, miso=miso)
spi.init()
rdr = MFRC522(spi=spi, gpioRst=4, gpioCs=5)
print("Place card")

while True:
    
    (stat, tag_type) = rdr.request(rdr.REQIDL)
    if stat == rdr.OK:
        print('ok')
        (stat, raw_uid) = rdr.anticoll()
        if stat == rdr.OK:
            card_id = "uid: 0x%02x%02x%02x%02x" % (raw_uid[0], raw_uid[1], raw_uid[2], raw_uid[3])
            print(card_id)
    else:
        print(stat)

And here is the associated mfrc522 library:
from machine import Pin, SPI
from os import uname

emptyRecv = b""

class MFRC522:

    GAIN_REG = 0x26
    MAX_GAIN = 0x07

    OK = 0
    NOTAGERR = 1
    ERR = 2

    REQIDL = 0x26
    REQALL = 0x52
    AUTHENT1A = 0x60
    AUTHENT1B = 0x61

    def __init__(self, spi=None, gpioRst=None, gpioCs=None):

        if gpioRst is not None:
            self.rst = Pin(gpioRst, Pin.OUT)
        else:
            self.rst = None
        assert(gpioCs is not None, "Needs gpioCs") # TODO fails without cableSelect
        if gpioCs is not None:
            self.cs = Pin(gpioCs, Pin.OUT)
        else:
            self.cs = None

        # TODO CH rationalise which of these are referenced, which can be identical
        self.regBuf = bytearray(4)
        self.blockWriteBuf = bytearray(18)
        self.authBuf = bytearray(12)
        self.wregBuf = bytearray(2)
        self.rregBuf = bytearray(1)
        self.recvBuf = bytearray(16)
        self.recvMv = memoryview(self.recvBuf)

        if self.rst is not None:
            self.rst.value(0)
        if self.cs is not None:
            self.cs.value(1)

        if spi is not None:
            self.spi = spi
        else:
            sck = Pin(14, Pin.OUT)
            mosi = Pin(13, Pin.OUT)
            miso = Pin(12, Pin.IN)
            if uname()[0] == 'WiPy':
                self.spi = SPI(0)
                self.spi.init(SPI.MASTER, baudrate=1000000, pins=(sck, mosi, miso))
            elif uname()[0] == 'esp8266': # TODO update to match https://github.com/cefn/avatap/blob/master/python/host/cockle.py #prepareHost()
                self.spi = SPI(baudrate=100000, polarity=0, phase=0, sck=sck, mosi=mosi, miso=miso)
                self.spi.init()
            else:
                raise RuntimeError("Unsupported platform")

        if self.rst is not None:
            self.rst.value(1)
        self.init()

    def _wreg(self, reg, val):
        if self.cs is not None:
            self.cs.value(0)
        buf = self.wregBuf
        buf[0]=0xff & ((reg << 1) & 0x7e)
        buf[1]=0xff & val
        self.spi.write(buf)
        if self.cs is not None:
            self.cs.value(1)

    def _rreg(self, reg):
        if self.cs is not None:
            self.cs.value(0)
        buf = self.rregBuf
        buf[0]=0xff & (((reg << 1) & 0x7e) | 0x80)
        self.spi.write(buf)
        val = self.spi.read(1)
        if self.cs is not None:
            self.cs.value(1)

        return val[0]

    def _sflags(self, reg, mask):
        self._wreg(reg, self._rreg(reg) | mask)

    def _cflags(self, reg, mask):
        self._wreg(reg, self._rreg(reg) & (~mask))

    def _tocard(self, cmd, send, into=None):

        recv = emptyRecv
        bits = irq_en = wait_irq = n = 0
        stat = self.ERR

        if cmd == 0x0E:
            irq_en = 0x12
            wait_irq = 0x10
        elif cmd == 0x0C:
            irq_en = 0x77
            wait_irq = 0x30

        self._wreg(0x02, irq_en | 0x80)
        self._cflags(0x04, 0x80)
        self._sflags(0x0A, 0x80)
        self._wreg(0x01, 0x00)

        for c in send:
            self._wreg(0x09, c)
        self._wreg(0x01, cmd)

        if cmd == 0x0C:
            self._sflags(0x0D, 0x80)

        i = 2000
        while True:
            n = self._rreg(0x04)
            i -= 1
            if ~((i != 0) and ~(n & 0x01) and ~(n & wait_irq)):
                break

        self._cflags(0x0D, 0x80)

        if i:
            if (self._rreg(0x06) & 0x1B) == 0x00:
                stat = self.OK

                if n & irq_en & 0x01:
                    stat = self.NOTAGERR
                elif cmd == 0x0C:
                    n = self._rreg(0x0A)
                    lbits = self._rreg(0x0C) & 0x07
                    if lbits != 0:
                        bits = (n - 1) * 8 + lbits
                    else:
                        bits = n * 8

                    if n == 0:
                        n = 1
                    elif n > 16:
                        n = 16

                    if into is None:
                        recv = self.recvBuf
                    else:
                        recv = into
                    pos = 0
                    while pos < n:
                        recv[pos] = self._rreg(0x09)
                        pos += 1
                    if into is None:
                        recv = self.recvMv[:n]
                    else:
                        recv = into

            else:
                stat = self.ERR

        return stat, recv, bits

    def _assign_crc(self, data, count):

        self._cflags(0x05, 0x04)
        self._sflags(0x0A, 0x80)

        dataPos = 0
        while dataPos < count:
            self._wreg(0x09, data[dataPos])
            dataPos += 1

        self._wreg(0x01, 0x03)

        i = 0xFF
        while True:
            n = self._rreg(0x05)
            i -= 1
            if not ((i != 0) and not (n & 0x04)):
                break

        data[count] = self._rreg(0x22)
        data[count + 1] = self._rreg(0x21)

    def init(self):

        self.reset()
        self._wreg(0x2A, 0x8D)
        self._wreg(0x2B, 0x3E)
        self._wreg(0x2D, 30)
        self._wreg(0x2C, 0)
        self._wreg(0x15, 0x40)
        self._wreg(0x11, 0x3D)
        self.set_gain(self.MAX_GAIN)
        self.antenna_on()


    def reset(self):
        self._wreg(0x01, 0x0F)

    def antenna_on(self, on=True):

        if on and ~(self._rreg(0x14) & 0x03):
            self._sflags(0x14, 0x03)
        else:
            self._cflags(0x14, 0x03)

    def request(self, mode):

        self._wreg(0x0D, 0x07)
        (stat, recv, bits) = self._tocard(0x0C, [mode])

        if (stat != self.OK) | (bits != 0x10):
            stat = self.ERR

        return stat, bits

    def anticoll(self):

        ser_chk = 0
        ser = [0x93, 0x20]

        self._wreg(0x0D, 0x00)
        (stat, recv, bits) = self._tocard(0x0C, ser)

        if stat == self.OK:
            if len(recv) == 5:
                for i in range(4):
                    ser_chk = ser_chk ^ recv[i]
                if ser_chk != recv[4]:
                    stat = self.ERR
            else:
                stat = self.ERR

        # CH Note bytearray allocation here
        return stat, bytearray(recv)

    def select_tag(self, ser):
        # TODO CH normalise all list manipulation to bytearray, avoid below allocation
        buf = bytearray(9)
        buf[0] = 0x93
        buf[1] = 0x70
        buf[2:7] = ser
        self._assign_crc(buf, 7)
        (stat, recv, bits) = self._tocard(0x0C, buf)
        return self.OK if (stat == self.OK) and (bits == 0x18) else self.ERR

    def auth(self, mode, addr, sect, ser):
        # TODO CH void ser[:4] implicit list allocation
        buf = self.authBuf
        buf[0]=mode # A or B
        buf[1]=addr # block
        buf[2:8]=sect # key bytes
        buf[8:12]=ser[:4] # 4 bytes of id
        return self._tocard(0x0E, buf)[0]

    # TODO this may well need to be implemented for vault to properly back out from a card session
    # TODO how, why, when is 'HaltA' needed? see https://github.com/cefn/micropython-mfrc522/issues/1
    def halt_a(self):
        pass

    def stop_crypto1(self):
        self._cflags(0x08, 0x08)

    def set_gain(self, gain):
        assert gain <= self.MAX_GAIN
        # clear bits
        self._cflags(self.GAIN_REG, 0x07<< 4)
        # set bits according to gain
        self._sflags(self.GAIN_REG, gain << 4)

    def read(self, addr, into = None):
        buf = self.regBuf
        buf[0]=0x30
        buf[1]=addr
        self._assign_crc(buf, 2)
        (stat, recv, _) = self._tocard(0x0C, buf, into=into)
        # TODO this logic probably wrong (should be 'into is None'?)
        if into is None: # superstitiously avoid returning read buffer memoryview
            # CH Note bytearray allocation here
            recv = bytearray(recv)
        return recv if stat == self.OK else None

    def write(self, addr, data):
        buf = self.regBuf
        buf[0] = 0xA0
        buf[1] = addr
        self._assign_crc(buf, 2)
        (stat, recv, bits) = self._tocard(0x0C, buf)

        if not (stat == self.OK) or not (bits == 4) or not ((recv[0] & 0x0F) == 0x0A):
            stat = self.ERR
        else:
            buf = self.blockWriteBuf

            i = 0
            while i < 16:
                buf[i] = data[i]  # TODO CH eliminate this, accelerate it?
                i += 1

            self._assign_crc(buf, 16)
            (stat, recv, bits) = self._tocard(0x0C, buf)
            if not (stat == self.OK) or not (bits == 4) or not ((recv[0] & 0x0F) == 0x0A):
                stat = self.ERR

        return stat

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have tried several combinations of SPI pins, and nothing thus far has worked. I always get stat=2 for the module, which appears to be a generic error code.

What exactly is the board you have? If you really have a C3 Xiao from SeeedStudio, the pinmap shows the SPI is on GPIO8-10, but if you something else that similar to a C3 Xiao (e.g. C3 Super Mini), then the pinmap may be different at GPIO4-6. So first thing, get to know your board first, if you are not sure, consult the vendor where you purchase the board from or post a photo of your board.

Thanks for the advice. The board I have is definitely a C3 Xiao (as I ordered it directly from seeedstudio). So perhaps the problem isn't with the pin mapping but how I'm setting up and using SPI in micro python?
